# Direct users to an application or Play Store page using a link without relying on any external website

Tags: android, reactjs, mobile, deep-linking, capacitor

I have developed a mobile application using React and converted it to Android and iOS using Capacitor. I want to redirect users to the application if it is installed, and to the Play Store page if it is not, using a link. I have looked at several examples, but they all relied on their own websites to redirect to the application. How can I make this without using a website?"

Comment: what you are asking is not possible as the deep-linking functionality requires you to have a server up and running.

Comment: but you can try checking out firebase dynamic links. this could be useful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.